# Solve the non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$ \dot{y} = \frac{3x^2}{y-x^2+1}$$

Substituting $u=y-x^2+1$ we get $\dot{u}=\dot{y}-2x$ we get $\dot{u}=\frac{3x^2}{y}-2x$. But I can't get any further now, i have tried substituting $k=u-x^2$, but it doesn't help.

Comment: what about Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner  Wolfram Alpha just gives graphical family by plotting y versus x for particular values.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \dot{y} = \frac{3x^2}{y-x^2+1}$$
$u=y-x^2+1\quad\to\quad \dot{u}=\dot{y}-2x =\frac{3x^2}{u}-2x$

$$u\dot{u}=-2xu+3x^2$$

This is an Abel's differential equation of the second kind.

In the present case, as far as I know, there is no standard special function available to express the general solution on a closed form. Use numerical calculus to solve it.

Comment: Complete solutions to Abel's equation of second kind may be found in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05929.pdf